# Wrap all the strings with single quotas

Tags: freemarker

Let's assume that my template is like a following

```
string1=${obj.firstString}
string2=${obj.secondString}
number1=${obj.firstNumber}
```

I'm looking for some automatic way to wrap all my string parameters with single quotas? The expected output is

```
string1='A'
string2='B'
number1=42
```

I understand that I can write `string1=${"'" + obj.firstString + "'"}` , but maybe there is some more conventional way for this requirement...

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just do this:

```
string1='${obj.firstString}'
string2='${obj.secondString}'
number1=${obj.firstNumber}
```

It's a template language, so the basic idea is to make your program look similar to its own output.